# Parse Json response android retrofit for dynamic values

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I am trying to parse JSON response in android. But not able to handle dynamic JSON format.

Here is a JSON response:

```
{
   "code":"1",
   "data":{
      "220":{
         "reg_no":"12",
         "device_status":"off"
      },
      "218":{
         "reg_no":"11",
         "device_status":"on"
      }
   }
}
```

220 and 219 are dynamic values.

Calling API from MainActivity.java

```
public void getItemData() {

    Call<ItemData> call = service.getItemData(token,vehicle_ids);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<ItemData>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ItemData> call,@NonNull Response<ItemData> response) {
            Log.d("Response",response.body.toString());

            progressDoalog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<ItemData> call,@NonNull Throwable t) {
            progressDoalog.dismiss();

        }
    });
}
```

Create ItemData Class to handle response:

ItemData.java

```
public class ItemData {

    private String code;
    private VehicleData data = new VehicleData();


    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(String code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public VehicleData getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setData(VehicleData data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

VehicleData.java

```
public class VehicleData{

}
```

I am getting response:

```
code: 1
data : null
```

Please suggest me How should I change my VehicleData.java class so that I can handle 
response.

Comment: The type for VehicleDate should be a HashMap<String, Object>.

Comment: I did it but I am getting data = size 0

Answer (score 0):

The same thing can also be done using GSON, but instead of using GSON converter adapter to convert into to POJO. we will parse it manually. which gives us flexibility in case of dynamic JSON data. 
let's say the JSON format is like below in my case.

```
  {
       "code":"1",
       "data":{
          "220":{
             "reg_no":"12",
             "device_status":"off"
          },
          "218":{
             "reg_no":"11",
             "device_status":"on"
          }
       }
    }
```

in this case the dateWiseContent has dynamic object keys so we will parse this json string using JsonParser class.

```
 //parsing string response to json object
 JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(resource);
  //getting root object
 JsonObject data = jsonObject.get("data").getAsJsonObject();
```

get the dynamic keys using Map.Entry as given below

```
// your code goes here
         for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> entry : data.entrySet()) {

           //this gets the dynamic keys
            String  dateKey = entry.getKey();

            //you can get any thing now json element,array,object according to json.

            JsonArray jsonArrayDates = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray();
            int appointmentsSize = jsonArrayDates.size();

             for (int count = 0; count < appointmentsSize; count++) {

                   JsonObject objectData = jsonArrayDates.get(count).getAsJsonObject();
                   String device_status = objectData.get("device_status").getAsString();


             }
        }
```

similarly any level of dynamic json can be parsed using Map.Entry

Comment: I already used jsonObject but I want to parse it using POJO class.

Comment: I am trying your answer, But I am getting this error ( This is not a JSON Array.) on line  JsonArray jsonArrayDates = entry.getValue().getAsJsonArray();

Comment: yes true @YogeshNikam because this was sample code not proper code and you have to replace with jsonObject method.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using Hashmap.

```
public class ItemData {

   Hashmap<String, object> data = new hashmap<>();

}
```

and using getter setter I can access variables.